# why is 'body' empty in nodejs express post request?

Tags: node.js, json, express, request, postman

I'm trying to catch raw data in the body that's sent by Postman. This is the raw data:

```
{
    "hello": "world"
}
```

I'm using `app.use(express.json())` in the server. When I send the post request I just get an empty JSON. Why is this happening?

App.js code:

```
import express from "express"
import { connectDb } from "./connectDb.js"
import create from "./routes/create.js" // router

const app = express()
app.use(express.json())

connectDb()

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.use("/api", create)

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(PORT, "Connected..."))
```

Router Code:

```
import express from "express"
import Game from "../models/gamesModel.js" // mongoose model
const router = express.Router()

router.route("/create/game").post(async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  try {
    const game = await Game.create(req.body)
    res.json(game)
  } catch (error) {
    res.json({ message: "Invalid Information" })
  }
})
```

Comment: We'd need to some some code please

Comment: This is your router. You need to both show how you server is setup, and how you send your request...

Comment: it is in the main javascript file (app.js) and it's used before the router code.

Comment: @AndreyPopov added (app.js) code...

Comment: In case you have not set the headers , With Postman, to test HTTP post actions with JSON data , select the raw option and set the following header parameters `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: @Deepakkumarjain Thanks man. That was the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct this in your headers:

```
content-type: application/json
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using POSTMAN to be able to access request body via `req.body` when you are using the buildin `express.json` middleware you will have to ensure that are send the request Body using `RAW` type and set the type of the body as `JSON` like in the image shown bellow

[image]

If the body type is set to something else (Text, JavScript, HTML, XML) You'll still getting an empty body. Only when it's set as `JSON` you will get `req.body` filled with data which you sent as part of you request body